# Angular momentum for elliptic path in 2D isotropic oscillator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, orbital-motion, harmonic-oscillator

Assume a 2D isotropic oscillator, i.e $$U = \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2(x^2+y^2),$$ and assume for simplicity that the oscillator performs elliptical motion, with major axis $A$ and semi-major axis $B$.

My answers show that the angular momentum of such motion is $$L = mAB\omega,$$ where $\omega$ is the frequency of oscillations. I was unable to derive this.

Is this true? How can one derive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [second Kepler Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Second_law), valid for any [central force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_force), states that
$$
\dot {\mathcal A}=\frac{1}{2}r^2\dot\theta=\frac{L}{2m} \tag{1}
$$
where $\dot {\mathcal A}$ is the [areal velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Areal_velocity). Integrating over one period,
$$
\pi AB=\frac{L}{2m}T \tag{2}
$$
where $\mathcal A=\pi AB$ is the [area of the ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Area).

If you use $(2)$ to solve for $L$, you get
$$
L=mAB \frac{2\pi}{T}=\omega m AB \tag{3}
$$
as required.